# How often, if ever, does the Imgur API refresh token expire?

Tags: imgur

I want to know how much time it takes for the Imgur API refresh tokens to expire. If they don't expire from time, what causes them to expire?

Answer (score 1):

The refresh token of the imgur API does not expire, check the official documentation on https://apidocs.imgur.com/#oauth-20-overview:

> - `refresh_token`: is used to request new access_tokens. Since access_tokens expire after 1 month, we need a way to request new ones without going through the entire authorization step again. **It does not expire**.